# Groovy replacing place holders of file content similar to multiline-string

Tags: groovy

Got the following script which replaces values in the multi line string.

```
def param1 = 'Groovy'
def param2 = 'Java'
def multiline = """
${param1} is closely related to ${param2},
so it is quite easy to make a transition.
"""
//output shows with the replaced values for param1 and param2
println multiline
```

*Output is shown as expected:*

```
Groovy is closely related to Java,
so it is quite easy to make a transition.
```

**Issue:**

Now I am trying to do the same using file instead of multi line string. i.e., copied the multi line string to a file and using the below script to do the same but not working(not giving the desired result).

I am sure, it must be something I am missing. Tried multiple way, but went futile.

**Try #1**: Script

```
def param1 = 'Groovy'
def param2 = 'Java'
def multiline = Eval.me(new File('test.txt').text)
println multiline
```

*And it fails to run.* Error follows:

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
>   Script1.groovy: 1: expecting EOF, found ',' @ line 1, column 42.
>      s closely related to ${param2},
>                                    ^
>   
> 1 error

**Try #2**

```
def param1 = 'Groovy'
def param2 = 'Java'
def multiline = new File('test.txt').text
def finalContent = """$multiline"""
println finalContent
```

And there is no difference in the output, just showing the file content as it is.

**Output:**

```
${param1} is closely related to ${param2},
so it is quite easy to make a transition.
```

Any pointers what am I missing?

*Please note that at the moment I want to avoid file content modification using `replace()` method.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why it doesn't work, however what I may suggest here is that [templating](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/template-engines.html) suits best here. Please have a look:

```
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine

def f = new File('lol.txt')
println f.text

def binding = [
    param1: 'Groovy',
    param2: 'Java',
]

def engine = new SimpleTemplateEngine()
def template = engine.createTemplate(f.text).make(binding)

println template.toString()
```

An explanation why file content is not evaluated may be found [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-2505).

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply. I though there might be something I am doing wrong. Thank you for the suggesting `template` which is me good thing to proceed. Will wait if someone explain what is wrong with what I tried.

Comment: @Rao, here you have an explanation: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-2505

Comment: Thank your for your time to go into the detail and refer to the problem cause, and happy to use `template`.