# String too long to evaluate in groovy

Tags: java, groovy, eval

I got a groovy script that works fine up until it gets too long. string is coming from ews xml and its a highly stipped html.

```
myHugeString = '''blablabla
andbla........
blablabla'''
```

eg.:

> String too long. The given string is 94073 Unicode code units long, but only a maximum of 65535 is allowed."

```
def a = Eval.me(myHugeString);
```

is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Why are you using so long string for evaluation? Why are you even doing string evaluation? What is the problem that's supposed to solve? And is any part of that string create by user input? Then you have a huge security problem.

Comment: That string is quite long. How is it generated? Does it have any patterns or repetitive content that can be wrapped in a loop?

Comment: string is coming from ews xml and its a highly stipped html. text + brs really.

Comment: Pass string to script through binding

Comment: @daggett can you please provide an example?

Comment: Please check if this thread helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38046210/groovy-replacing-place-holders-of-file-content-similar-to-multiline-string

Comment: `Eval.me( 'myHugeString', ewsXml, ''' println myHugeString.length ''' )`